# changing the text color of a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

Hi Im trying to change the text color of a UILabel in one of my views but having no luck.

Is there something quite obvious that Im not doing in this code?

```
self.nameTopRight.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.nameBottomRight.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They need to be connected in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 23):

The question was already answered for the OP, but for the sake of other people who come here trying to change a label's text color, use the `textColor` property:

Swift

```swift
myLabel.textColor = UIColor.red  // or .red
```

Objective-C

```objectivec
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the UIColor via RGB values like so:

```
myLabel.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Text color is the correct one, may be mistake in connections,

backgroundcolor is used for the label background color and for the textcolor use property textcolor